# How to create a patch with English ASCII header by Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, locale, patch

My Windows's locale is Chinese/Code Page 936. When I create a patch by Tortoise SVN (even if the Tortoise SVN is in English UI), it create a patch file with header like this:

```
Index: C:/mypath/myfile.txt
===================================================================
--- C:/mypath/myfile.txt    (版本 3174)
+++ C:/mypath/myfile.txt    (工作副本)
```

The characters `(工作副本)` in header is GBK(CP936) encoded. And my `myfile.txt` is a UTF-8 file, so the content of the patch is UTF-8 encoded. The whole patch file is mixed encoded, which is bad.

How can I make the patch's header be in English and ASCII?

Comment: Can you use the command line client?

Comment: Yes, the command line one works fine!

Answer (score 1):

While this does not solve the TortoiseSVN problem, you can generate the patches with a command line client like Windows Powershell . You can disable the translation there, when you set the environment variable `LC_ALL` to C.

```
:: disable the translation
set LC_ALL=C
:: create the patch
svn diff {diff params} > patch.diff
```